# Wrong overload selected for stream manipulator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++builder, overload-resolution, c++builder-xe6

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <typeinfo>

#if 0
std::ostream &foo(std::ostream &os, std::ios_base &(*x)(std::ios_base &), bool show_id = false)
{ 
    if ( show_id )
        os << "(" << typeid(x).name() << ") ";
    return os << x;
}
#endif

template<typename T>
std::ostream &foo(std::ostream &os, T const &t, bool show_id = false)
{
    if ( show_id )
        os << "(" << typeid(t).name() << ") ";

    return os << t;
}

int main()
{
    foo(std::cout, std::hex) << 255 << std::endl;
    foo(std::cout, ".") << std::hex << 255 << std::dec << std::endl;

    foo(std::cout, std::hex, true) << 255 << std::endl;
}
```

Using bcc32 6.70 and bcc32 5.82, the output is

```
401358255
.ff
(std::ios_base & (*)(std::ios_base &) const) 401368255
```

Using bcc64 6.70 (based on clang) and g++ 4.8.2, the output is

```
ff
.ff
(FRSt8ios_baseS0_E) ff
```

I presume clang and gcc are correct, because they have better reputations than bcc32.

If I enable the commented-out function, then bcc32 outputs:

```
ff
.ff
(std::ios_base & (*)(std::ios_base &)) ff
```

What exactly is going wrong with the first version? It's presumably a compiler bug to do with overload resolution, but I can't figure out what bcc32 is doing, or what the `const` is on the end of the `typeid` output.

Comment: Update, if I change `os << t;` to `os << const_cast<T &>(t)`, then bcc32 gives `E2094: 'operator<<' not implemented in type 'ostream' for arguments of type 'std::ios_base &(std::ios_base &)'` which doesn't make much sense since that's exactly what the type of `hex` etc. is

Comment: are you able to try bcc32 6.80 from XE6?

Comment: Not immediately - but if anyone reading this with XE6 would like to run my code, that would be great

Comment: Reported as [QC#124805](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=124805)