# Transparent passing C++ variadic call parameters to ostream output operator

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions, rvalue-reference

I have written myself the following function:

```cpp
template <class Stream>
inline Stream& Print(Stream& in) { return in;}

template <class Stream, class Arg1, class... Args>
inline Stream& Print(Stream& sout, Arg1&& arg1, Args&&... args)
{
    sout << arg1;
    return Print(sout, args...);
}
```

It should make it useful to replace code like:

```
cout << "This took " << ns << " seconds with " << np << " packets.\n";
```

with

```
Print(cout, "This took ", ns, " seconds with ", np, " packets.\n");
```

And everything works fine, except that this function doesn't "tolerate" some manipulators. What is funny, only some of them. If you replace, for example, `" packets.\n"` with `" packets.", endl`, it will no longer compile. Although `hex` or `setw(20)` is fine. Where is the problem?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24377892

Comment: You should use perfect forwarding in the recursive call `return Print(sout, std::forward<Args>(args)...);` out of a habit. It's not a big deal in this case, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is a function template.

So it cannot be deduced as for overloaded functions.

```
static_cast<std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&)>(&std::endl)
```

would select correct overload.

```
using Manipulator = std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&);

Print(std::cout, "This took ", ns, " seconds with ", np, " packets.", Manipulator(std::endl));
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9f7MKd9sf)

Since C++14, you might even not hard code type of stream with an helper:

```
template <typename T>
struct ManipulatorImpl
{
    ManipulatorImpl(T t) : t(t) {}

    T t;
};

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, ManipulatorImpl<T> m)
{
    return m.t(os);
}

template <typename T>
ManipulatorImpl<T> make_ManipulatorImpl(T t) { return {t}; }

#define Manipulator(name) make_ManipulatorImpl([](auto& os) -> decltype((name)(os)) { return (name)(os); })
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KoGnWvh3j)

Comment: Although I don't really like the solution with a pp macro, at least it gives me an idea to fix it. I checked also what happens, if I put `isprint` instead of `endl` and yes, it results with the same error. Thanks a log!

Comment: Unfortunately, when manipulating **name**, MACRO is the only way. (Fortunately, we don't have to manipulate name so often).

Comment: Yeah, saw that. That's why I was also attempting to resolve it by overloading the comma operator ;)

Answer (score 2):

I can't explain the exact reason, but if I do something like this it doesn't throw an error:

```cpp
endl<char, char_traits<char>>
```

My guess is that it doesn't seem to be able to do template type parameter inference.
The ostream is:

```cpp
using ostream = basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char>>;
```